# Wood Counter Top Damage

Tags: water, wood, damage, stain

I have a wood countertop w/ dark water stain damage, I'm looking for ways to fix.
I tried sanding and it just made the area around the stain lighter. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll either need to sand or scrape until you get to unstained wood, or try a bleaching product (oxalic acid is a common "wood bleach") to alter the color of the stained wood without removing it.